# Carrier Wave mini_magick_processing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to upload an image in my signup form using carrierwave gem but getting this error:

> Avatar translation missing: en.errors.messages.mini_magick_processing_error

This is my form:

```
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :avatar %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    <%= f.submit "SignUp", class: "btn btn-primary button" %>

   <% end %>
   <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
```

and this is my AvatarUploader:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
   def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
   end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
   version :thumb do
     process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
   end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
   def extension_whitelist
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Comment: This is not the error, it is only the indication that an error occourred and you do not have the translation i18n of it's term. Try saving the model with a bang! like **save!** to see the stacktrace and identify the real error. Is imagemagick library installed? Check minimagick's dependencies.